# Where's the problem with this BoundedBuffer class?

Tags: java, concurrency

Properties of the bounded buffer class I'm trying to build...

- Multiple producer, multiple consumer.
- Blocking producer and blocking consumer.
- Uses AtomicInteger as the read/write pointers.
- Uses AtomicReferenceArray (taking in a generic type) for holding the buffer.
- Buffer is of Short.MAX_VALUE size and it uses CAS to deal with overflows.

Now for the problem...

**Problem:** I can't seem to comment out the **synchronized(this) blocks** in the code below. The whole point of using AtomicInteger as pointers I thought was to avoid doing this.

Commenting out the synchronized(this) blocks yields in consumers missing some items that producers have put in. If I include the synchronized(this) block, everything's great and every single thing produced is consumed.

What am I missing?

```
public class BoundedBuffer<T> {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = Short.MAX_VALUE+1;
    private AtomicReferenceArray<T> m_buffer = null;
    private Semaphore m_full = new Semaphore(BUFFER_SIZE);
    private Semaphore m_empty = new Semaphore(0);
    private AtomicInteger m_writePointer = new AtomicInteger();
    private AtomicInteger m_readPointer = new AtomicInteger();

    public BoundedBuffer() {
        m_buffer = new AtomicReferenceArray<T>(BUFFER_SIZE);
    }

    public static int safeGetAndIncrement(AtomicInteger i) {
        int oldValue = 0, newValue = 0;
        do {
            oldValue = i.get();
            newValue = (oldValue == Short.MAX_VALUE) ? 0 : (oldValue + 1);
        } while (!i.compareAndSet(oldValue, newValue));
        return oldValue;
    }

    public void add(T data) throws InterruptedException {
        m_full.acquire();
        synchronized (this) { // << Commenting this doesn't work
            // CAS-based overflow handling
            m_buffer.set(safeGetAndIncrement(m_writePointer),data);
        }
        m_empty.release();
    }

    public T get() throws InterruptedException {
        T data = null;
        m_empty.acquire();
        synchronized (this) { // << Commenting this doesn't work
            // CAS-based overflow handling
            data = m_buffer.get(safeGetAndIncrement(m_readPointer));
        }
        m_full.release();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you deal with index overflow when writing a thread-safe blocking bounded buffer structure in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374032/how-do-you-deal-with-index-overflow-when-writing-a-thread-safe-blocking-bounded-b)

Comment: In `safeGetAndIncrement` you've coded `...(oldValue == Short.MAX_VALUE)...`.  This should be `...(oldValue == BUFFER_SIZE - 1)...`. It's a small point but otherwise if you decide to change BUFFER_SIZE to some other value, you'll need to change this line too or your code will break.

Comment: @Adrian I've fixed that since I posted the code. I realized that too. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a problem where the get() from the array is not atomic with the increment when the synchronized block is removed. The breaking scenario I speculate on requires the producer to be overrunning the consumers, then you could have the producer overwrite an array entry that has not been read yet IF the semaphore release was triggered by an out-of-order read.

Consider the situation where the buffer is full (writer index is at N, reader index is at N+1) and 2 threads are trying to read from the buffer. (Assume that N is not close to the wraparound point for simplicity.)

Thread 1 receives the index N+1 from which to read its item.

Thread 2 receives the index N+2 from which to read its item.

Due to a fluke of scheduling Thread 2 gets from the buffer array first and releases the `m_full` semaphore before Thread 1 gets its item from the array.

Thread 3 (a producer) wakes up and writes an item into the next available slot N+1 in the buffer, also before Thread 1 has read from the buffer.

Thread 1 then gets the item at index N+1, but has missed the item it wanted.

Comment: Sounds plausible, I see it too now. I wonder if there's a fix though? I tried to reduce the number of full semaphore's handed out initially to half the size of the buffer -- such that there's always about 1/2 the space in the buffer free and the read/write pointers are always far apart. This still doesn't fix it.

Comment: Probably something else then. Is it possible to add some logging to see what's going on, or does that make the problem go away?

Comment: You could also try only removing one or other of the synchronized blocks to see if it only has problems on one side of the put/get.

Comment: Right now there's three missing entries when producing/consuming 8 Million entries. Not sure where I'd even start to add logging :)

Comment: Do you get any other anomalies, like having the same value consumed twice, or consuming an unexpected `null`? (I am hinting at a similar problem that could exist based on out-of-order release of the empty semaphore on write.)

Comment: This second problem I am describing relates to the empty semaphore, rather than the full semaphore. Basically it is the same scenario though, but this time the read thread ends up reading an index (N, say) that hasn't been written to yet because the empty semaphore gets release()d by a producer writing to index N+1 (while another producer acquired index N but hasn't written to it yet). This would result in the consumer reading either a `null` value or a value that has been read before.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't think I can get rid of the synchronized block in this fashion. Do you think there's a solution? I can't see it.